# Isekai manhwa where the villainess's sister, named Dylan, marries the male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Manhwa where the Female Lead is reincarnated as the villainess's sister and tries to persuade the original Male Lead from marrying her sister and instead she marries him and the Female Lead's name is Dylan I think.

Comment: Hi Amy (?), please take a look at [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/107946), and see what information you can add to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: *I Reincarnated as the Little Sister of a Death Game Manga’s Murd3r Mastermind and Failed*?

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the male lead?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[For Better or for Worse](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/for-better-or-for-worse)*. It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/for-better-or-for-worse/info).

> The spunky **Lady Dillion** didn't realize she was the villain of a romance novel until she encounters Marquess Cedric. Seeing him jogs a dormant memory of the novel's plot, in which **her beloved younger sister dies in childbirth after marrying Cedric. Determined to prevent this**, Dillion marries him herself, but what fate awaits her when she knows he's meant to fall in love with the real female lead later? In this marriage of convenience, it seems nothing turns out quite how either of them expects...

[image: Cover image]

The protagonist is Dillion Langton, the villainess of a story she reincarnated into many years ago. Her sister Emily is an unnamed extra in the original story, referred to only as the Duke's former wife, as she dies in child birth before the events of the story.

The male lead Cedric comes to their estate specifically to marry, due to a promise made between their grandparents. Knowing the fate of her sister if she were to marry him, she tries to drive him away from the estate. This partially works, as he proposes to Dillion instead.